# How to change response type from Java Servlet

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, servlets, gson

I have successfully completed the Android Studio Java servlets module [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/HelloWorld). I am trying to change the response I receive from the server and display it as a toast. I set up the example and received a toast that said "Hello" + name. I then changed the text in the res.getWriter() method, as shown below:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {
    resp.setContentType("text/plain");
    resp.getWriter().println("Please use the form to POST to this url");
}

@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {
    String name = req.getParameter("name");
    resp.setContentType("text/plain");
    if(name == null) {
        resp.getWriter().println("Please enter a name");
    }
    resp.getWriter().println("A test to change text" + name);
  }
}
```

Here is my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView mNumberCounter;
Button mIncrease;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mNumberCounter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number_counter);
    mIncrease = (Button) findViewById(R.id.increase_button);


    mIncrease.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new ServletPostAsyncTask().execute(new Pair<Context, String>(getApplicationContext(), mNumberCounter.getText().toString()));
        }
    });
  }
}
```

And the ServletPostAsyncTask class:

```
public class ServletPostAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<android.support.v4.util.Pair<Context, String>, Void, String> {
private Context context;

@Override
    protected String doInBackground(android.support.v4.util.Pair<Context, String>... params) {
    context = params[0].first;
    String name = params[0].second;

    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://servlet-example-1198.appspot.com/hello");
    try {
        // Add name data to request
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
            return EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        }
        return "Error: " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() + " " + response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        return e.getMessage();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return e.getMessage();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    Toast.makeText(context, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

  }
}
```

Unfortunately, I am still receiving the response of "Hello" + the number 1 that I have in my TextView, when I expect it to now say "A test to change text.: I am looking on how to change this text and also change the server response types, i.e. if I want to receive a boolean or a int instead of simple text. From what I understand, this is handled in the resp.setContentType(), but I am looking for some guidance.

Comment: Are you sure you redeployed the new version to "http://servlet-example-1198.appspot.com/hello" ? Modify the _doGet_ method to return something else, then paste the URL in a browser and check that.

Comment: I ran the server module in Android Studio, so I am sure I redeployed it to the server. Why should I have to change anything in the doGet() method?

Comment: doGet() would diplay immediately its response in a browser, and is easier to call (GET method is the default in a browser), so it makes it easier to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting, maybe somebody can help explain the difference. When I simply click the green arrow for my app module, that does not push to the server, however the Build > Deploy Module to App Engine resolved my issue. Wasn't sure that there was a difference..

[image]